# How to get old value of a field in a fucntion - Odoo12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to get the old value of a field in `onchange` method.

Here is what I tried.

```
@api.onchange('assigned_to')
# @api.depends('assigned_to')
def onchange_assigned_to(self):
    print('onchange_assigned_to')
    history = self._origin.read(["assigned_to"])
    if history:
        id = history[0]["assigned_to"][0]
        last_assigned = self.env['res.users'].browse([id])
        self.last_assign_id = last_assigned
```

The above code is working and I getting the old value only if I change the field value through GUI.

I am also changing the field value via button action., that time this function is not working.

How can I achieve this?

And I also tried on compute function with `@api.depends`.

That time I got an

> 'AttributeError: 'crm.lead' object has no attribute '_origin''

Comment: In the end your `assigned_to` will be written per `write()` so i would implement your logic right into the `write()` instead of doing it right in an "onchange"-environment. The button thing won't work, because there is a call on `write()` before calling anything the button has defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this in write method, and will always work, you can keep the onchange
if you want to give a feedback to the user:

```py
     @api.multi
     def write(vals):
        """ keep assignment history. """
        if 'assigned_to' in vals:  # keep assignment history
            # no need to keep it in vals here
            vals.pop('last_assign_id', None)

            for rec in self:
                rec.last_assign_id = rec.assigned_to

        return super(ClassName, self).write(vals)
```